# Deriving the BBP identify for $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-number-theory, mathematica

I was given a problem to learn how to use Mathematica. I should derive the identity from the paper [1](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1997-66-218/S0025-5718-97-00856-9/S0025-5718-97-00856-9.pdf) known as the BBP formula for $\pi$. But I can't figure it out why

$$\begin{equation} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16^k}(\frac{4}{8i+1} - \frac{2}{8i+4}-\frac{1}{8i+5}-\frac{1}{8i+6}) = \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{4\sqrt{2}-8x^3-4\sqrt{2}x^4-8x^5}{1-x^8} {dx} \end{equation}$$

holds while using

$$\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^8} {dx} = \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{k-1}x^{8i} {dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^k} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16i(8i+k)}
\end{equation}$$

this. I don't see how I can figure this out neither in Mathematica nor by hand.

Comment: You cn get displayed equations by using double instead of single dollar signs. That's especially relevant when you're mixing fractions and integral limits.

Comment: Which step are you missing, more precisely ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by writing
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} &\frac{4\sqrt{2}-8x^3-4\sqrt{2}x^4-8x^5}{1-x^8} dx = 
\\&
4 \sqrt{2}\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{x^0}{1-x^8} dx 
- 
8\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{x^3}{1-x^8} dx 
\\ & \qquad - 
4 \sqrt{2}\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{x^4}{1-x^8} dx 
- 
8\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{x^5}{1-x^8} dx
\end{align}
$$